# Create an alert on alertmanager using curl

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I came across this need and could not find a simple answer:

I have a Prometheus + Alertmanager setup and want to test
the alertmanager third party integrations.

So I wanted to create a dummy alert without having to change rules on prometheus and etc.

How can I create a test alert on alertmanager?

Comment: I think it would be better if you edit this question to look like question, and post answer separately. And don't forgot to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do it =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case someone else has the same need sometime, it can be achieved by a simple curl command like bellow

```
curl -w '\n' -i --user 'admin:admin' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '[{"labels":{"alertname":"test_opsgenie", "team":"opsgenie"},"endsAt":"2023-03-21T00:10:53-03:00"}]' \
  http://alertmanager_url:9093/api/v1/alerts
```

Comment: You can also use the "test" route. This is a built-in route in Alertmanager that allows you to send test alerts to your configured receivers without actually triggering any alerts from your monitoring system.