# Can we pass rules to Prometheus Alert Manager without using Prometheus rules ? Any alternatives to the Prometheus Rules?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I am trying to find a way to use Prometheus Alert Manager without using Prometheus rules.
Can we create Alert Rules in any alternative way without making use of Prometheus and integrate it with Alert Manager or is it not possible at all ?
Is it that currently Alert Manager is dependent only on Prometheus config for alert rules or is there any way to separate out both of them.
Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "create Alert Rules in any alternative way"? Alertmanager is a service of routing, silencing and aggregating alert sent to it. You can send alert there even with simple curl. Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75807372/21363224). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are asking, but one option is to use Grafana both as a way to centralise prometheus data but also to have a much richer set of alerting functionality.

Comment: @markalex Thanks a lot for the comment. I meant to say that there are many documents available for integration between Prometheus and alert manager. But suppose, if I do not want to use Prometheus config to create a set of alert rules for alert manager. Then, what are the different options that I can use in my environment to define set of alert rules and integrate those with alert manager

Comment: @LukeBriner thankyou for the suggestion. I will explore grafana to be used as an alerting mechanism