# Alertmanager API when running with Prometheus as docker services

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm having Alertmanager and Prometheus running as docker services.
Alertmanager is configured to send emails if there are alerts triggered.

What I want to do is to be able to use Alertmanager config [in my case emails] and send emails alerts outside of Prometheus [e.g.: having a cronjob that's doing something else, but I want notifications based on its output]

Can I do that?

Comment: Surely you can: use curl to pass alert objects to alertmanager https://stackoverflow.com/a/75807372/21363224

Comment: I'm receiving 404

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2023 07:24:49 GMT
Content-Length: 19

404 page not found

Comment: Version Information
Branch:
HEAD
BuildDate:
20221222-14:51:36
BuildUser:
root@abe866dd5717
GoVersion:
go1.19.4
Revision:
258fab7cdd551f2cf251ed0348f0ad7289aee789
Version:
0.25.0

Comment: Nope, was my fault because I have some other configs, everything is working