Slack alerts into Webex Team
I'm trying to migrate Prometheus Alertmanager alerting from using slack_configs (ref1) into the webex_configs (ref2). Is there any possibility to adjust the message sent to Webex with structure used in "old" slack_configs? Following structure is needed:
<Title composed of .Status + text eg 'Event Notification'>
Alert - < Annotations.Summary + Labes.severity >
Message - < Annotations.message >
Graph - < GeneralURL >, Dashboard < Annotations.dashboardurl >
Details ( composed of Labels.SortedPairs (Name + Value))

I know this is possible via webhook_configs + proxy, however If there's possibility to create this without the need of proxy, that would be ideal.
- ref1
- name: alerts
        slack_configs:
          - api_url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            channel: '#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            http_config:
              proxy_url: XXXXXXXXXXX
            text: |-
              {{ `{{ range .Alerts }}
                *Alert:* {{ .Annotations.summary }} - {{ .Labels.severity }}
                *Message:* {{ .Annotations.message }}
                *Graph:* <{{ .GeneratorURL }}|:chart_with_upwards_trend:> *Dashboard:* <{{ .Annotations.dashboardurl }}|:bar_chart:>
                *Details:*
                {{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }} • *{{ .Name }}:* {{ .Value }}
                {{ end }}
              {{ end }}` }}
            title: |-
              {{ `[{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] Notification` }}

- ref2
- name: alerts_webex
        webex_configs:
          - api_url: 'https://webexapis.com/v1/messages'
            room_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            send_resolved: false
            http_config:
              proxy_url: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
              authorization:
                type: 'Bearer'
                credentials: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            message: |-
              {{ `{{ range .Alerts }}
                "**{{ .Status }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }} Notification**\n\n*Severity:* {{ .Labels.severity }}\n**Alert:** {{ .Annotations.summary }}\n**Message:** {{ .Annotations.message }}\n**Graph:** [Graph URL]({{ .GeneratorURL }})\n**Dashboard:** [Dashboard URL]({{ .Annotations.dashboardurl }})\n**Details:**\n{{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }} • **{{ .Name }}:** {{ .Value }}\n{{ end }}"
              {{ end }}` }}

Note: Alerts from webex_configs don't arrive at any point, without any errors produced & connection working fine. slack_configs fully functional, even when using both configurations together with routes & continue: true for receivers, only slack receives the alert.

This feels like two completely unrelated problems. 1. Messages are not sent to webex. and 2. You don't know how to format message to webex. First one is off-topic for SO, since it is not development related. I suggest you checking out logs, and rechecking if all configurations for webex are correct. And if needed, asking a separate question (omitting whole ordeal about templates, and using simple dummy message instead) on [su] or [devops.se].

And once that is solved (and if you stil have troubles with template to that point) asking question dedicated to templates.

@markalex you are correct, didn't put this as straightforward as intended. The problem is the mix of two, because 1. Messages are not sent to webex but 2. this is 99% caused by template. So in this situation, it is problem of the template. I have created simple condition, when there are no alerts, message would be sent to Webex with super simple text "No Alerts". This would work, the messages would arrive in the end, however they get lost or are not generated or I'm not sure what, when I try to use template mentioned above.

Hmm. I recall templates being sent without substitution if they are wrong, but I guess it might depend. Still very much recommend checking logs. And if there is nothing interesting  there, starting with simple dummy message and increasing complexity of template as it goes.

You can trigger alert from outside to speedup tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75807372/21363224

@markalex that was good point, I setup Alertmanager locally with personal Webex space, for easier troubleshooting. The issue with arriving/not arriving alerts is pretty much solved. The issue was with conditionals and bit of formatting. However new issue. When printing out simple alert status {{ . Status }}, the value shows nicely (firing/resolved). However when trying to print out the values in nested data for example {{ .Labels.Alertname }} then the Values will be blank. It's weird because if you use just {{ .Labels }}, all of the key-value data in that section is printed out.

[Edit] your question and localize it around this issue.
